# Number of Equilibrium Points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the question:
Find the number of equilibrium points for

$y′=y^3−y+h$

for $h=−1,0,1$

How do I find equilibrium points?  The only thing I could think of was to plug h into the equation, which obviously doesn't help my case.  I was told that an equilibrium point occurred when $y'=0$, but I'm not sure how to get there.  Does anyone know how to get all the equilibrium points for this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: Was the answer helpful and clear?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the answer and the excellent graph.  I  was too busy to get on before, I apologize for not responding earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, equilibrium points occur when $y' = 0$

So we have:

- $h = -1, y' = y^3 - y -1 = 0 \rightarrow y = 1.32471795$ (We ignore the imaginary roots.)
- $h = 0, y' = y^3 - y  = 0 \rightarrow y = -1, 0 , 1$
- $h = +1, y' = y^3 - y +1 = 0 \rightarrow y = -1.32471795$ (We ignore the imaginary roots.)

These equilibrium points help us with a direction field plot.

We have, for $h = -1$, a single equilibrium point at $y = 1.32471795$:

[image]

We have, for $h = 0$, three equilibrium points at $y = -1, 0, 1$:

[image]

We have, for $h = +1$, a single equilibrium point at $y = -1.32471795$:

[image]

Do you notice what we see at the equilibrium points we calculated?

Comment: Excellent visuals, as usual! +1

Comment: Nice as usual. I love plotting. +1